# How do I write to a slave using StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/) to talk to a pair of Redis servers, a master and a slave.  When I fail the master, I am unable to write to the slave.

I have `IServer.AllowSlaveWrites` set to `true`, and I have the `slave-read-only` config setting set to `no` on both servers. (Confirmed by INFO.)

When the master is still in the client's server pool (but offline), I get:

```
RedisConnectionException: SocketFailure on <master_ip>/Subscription
```

If I take the master out of the server pool entirely, I get:

```
RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this operation: SET ...
```

In the first case, it seems to be trying to talk to the master, and giving up on failure.  In the second, it's talking to the slave but can't execute write operations.

How do I get my client to write to a slave server without a master present?

(See also [How does StackExchange.Redis use multiple endpoints and connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29247616/222481))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the library is hardcoded to not allow write operations to slaves.

In the constructor of `Message` (Message.cs, line 170), there is the following code:

```
bool masterOnly = IsMasterOnly(command);
if (masterOnly) SetMasterOnly();
```

`IsMasterOnly()` returns `true` for all write commands.  `SetMasterOnly()` overrides any master/slave flags the user supplied in favor of `CommandFlags.DemandMaster`.  When the system tries to write to a slave, this flag triggers the `RedisConnectionException` quoted above.

I'm not sure why this hardcoded override is in there, as the `AllowSlaveWrites` flag *and* the `slave_read_only` config value already protect from accidental slave writes (see `WriteMessageToServer()`).

In any case, removing these lines from Message.cs seems to allow for the expected operation.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue. Here is how I fixed it:

```
IConnectionMultiplexer con = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("127.0.0.1:6379");
IDatabase db = con.GetDatabase();
db.Execute("ZINTERSTORE", key, 2, first, second, "WEIGHTS", 0, 1);
```

As you can see above `db.Execute` method would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
IServer ser = RedisConn.GetServer("192.168.1.1", 6379);
ser.AllowSlaveWrites = true;
ser.Execute("set",new object[2] { "test",1});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.