# Can you have a single end point for Redis cluster(master/slave)?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I've started reading on how to set-up a Redis cluster and most of the bits of information make sense except the fact that I can't find what will be the common end point of the cluster that I spawn.

Since I am considering using Sentinel to mitigate the fail-overs as well as considering to make the slaves read-only, I would expect that there is some out of the box client that would manage load balancing for me. For C# there is [StackExchange.Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247616/how-does-stackexchange-redis-use-multiple-endpoints-and-connections) that does exactly that, is there some open source solution in Java? Since one has to write a separate client to manage this, there is no out of the box support from Redis to manage multiple hosts?

Comment: There is no common end points in Redis cluster . Each node keeps information of each node and slots which that node will serve. Lettuce is great library (smart java client) which cache the nodes and their serving slots to save redirection time while read/write data. It also has features like refresh cluater topology automatically,read from slave options

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

It's possible, but not (out-of-the-box) with [jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis).

## Explanation

Jedis supports Redis Sentinel in the sense of high availability but it has no support for slave reads. Using Jedis will read always from the current master node. You can however obtain slaves from Sentinel (`SENTINEL SLAVES <master-name>`) and spin up own clients. Jedis has currently an [open ticket](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/1400) to implement that feature.

Alternatively, you might want to check out [lettuce](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce/wiki/Master-Slave) or [Redisson](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration#27-sentinel-mode).

Both clients provide master lookup and control over the [read behavior](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce/wiki/ReadFrom-Settings).

Answer (score 0):

You should connect all redis nodes.
I've tried lettuce. It was steel the same. Here is 
[AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Endpoints.html)

Comment: It is a comment, not answer. Please write something more, otherwise, it will be closed soon.